# ClientDisconnectedError from aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, python-3.4, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have a websocket server built with aiohttp.
I keep getting this exception in the server error stream.

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<read() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/aiohttp/streams.py:576> exception=ClientDisconnectedError()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 234, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 578, in read
    result = yield from super().read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 433, in read
    yield from self._waiter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 386, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 287, in _wakeup
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 275, in result
    raise self._exception
aiohttp.errors.ClientDisconnectedError
```

The client shows a message as:

```
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f67ec0f0588>
```

The code in the handler is:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def sync(self, request):
    ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
    yield from ws.prepare(request)

    # while True:
    msg = yield from ws.receive()
    if msg.tp == aiohttp.MsgType.text:
        payload = msg.data
        pypayload = json.loads(payload)
        result = {'result': {}}
        for store in pypayload:
            try:
                sync_obj = yield from asyncio.async(self.prepare(store))
            except (IndexError, TypeError, ValidationError) as exc:
                yield from asyncio.async(self.handle_internal_error(exc, store))
            else:
                try:
                    sync_result, request_type = yield from asyncio.async(self.send_data(sync_obj))
                except DuplicateMappingsFound as exc:
                    yield from asyncio.async(self.handle_internal_error(exc, store))
                else:
                    if sync_result.status == 200 and request_type == 'post':
                        yield from asyncio.async(self.process_data(sync_result))
                    elif sync_result.status >= 400:
                        yield from asyncio.async(self.handle_error(sync_result, sync_obj))
                    result['result'].update(
                            {store['store_id']: sync_result.status}
                        )
                    yield from asyncio.async(sync_result.release())
        ws.send_str(json.dumps(result))
    elif msg.tp == aiohttp.MsgType.error:
        print('ws connection closed with exception {0}'.format(ws.exception()))

    yield from asyncio.async(ws.close())

    print('websocket connection closed')

    return ws
```

The client code is:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def sync_store():
    resp = yield from aiohttp.get('http://localhost/stores/search')
    stores = yield from resp.json()
    total_page = stores['page']['total_page']
    page = stores['page']['current_page']
    total_resp = []
    ws_sockets = []
    while True:
        for page in range(page, total_page):
            session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
            ws = yield from asyncio.async(session.ws_connect('ws://localhost:8765/stores'))
            ws_sockets.append(ws)
            ws.send_str(json.dumps(stores['data']))
            resp = yield from asyncio.async(ws.receive())
            total_resp.append(resp.data)
            # print(resp)
            stores_resp = yield from asyncio.async(aiohttp.post('http://localhost/stores/search',
                                                                data=json.dumps({'page': page+1}),
                                                                headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
                                                                ))
            stores = yield from asyncio.async(stores_resp.json())
        while ws_sockets:
            session = ws_sockets.pop(0)
            msg = yield from session.receive()
            if not(msg.tp == aiohttp.MsgType.close or msg.tp == aiohttp.MsgType.closed):
                ws_sockets.append(session)
            else:
                print(ws_sockets)
        break
    print(total_resp)
```

What could be the problem with this?
I also tried enabling the debugging mode but that also doesn't seem to give any useful output.

Comment: Why are you wrapping every call in `asyncio.async`? If you're just going to `yield from` the result of a coroutine right away, there's no need to wrap it in a `Future`, it just adds unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I added the yield from to chain the result of the futures in the correct order and wrapped the calls in asyncio.async is for releasing the control if its waiting, since this will be part of a server I don't want to block or am i misunderstanding something over here?